# using RestSharp to data deserialization

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Want to get `authority` from json `response`. the `response` return:

```
"{\"data\":{\"code\":100,\"message\":\"Success\",\"authority\":\"S00000000000000000000000000354760561\",\"fee_type\":\"Merchant\",\"fee\":0},\"errors\":[]}"
```

I use this class to deserialize that:

```
public class PaymentResponse
{
    public string authority { get; set; }
}
```

but `responseList[0].authority` return `null`!

```
var response = client.Execute(request); //Work properly 
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
var responseList = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<PaymentResponse>>(response);
return responseList[0].authority; //return null!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
   "data":{
      "code":100,
      "message":"Success",
      "authority":"S00000000000000000000000000354760561",
      "fee_type":"Merchant",
      "fee":0
   },
   "errors":[
      
   ]
}
```

Your PaymentResponse class has only the property
authority. In order for the json return to be properly deserilized your class would have to look like this:

```cs
    public class Data
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string authority { get; set; }
        public string fee_type { get; set; }
        public int fee { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: To add to @Faedrak's response, your PaymentResponse class would need to have a property of type Data in order for Serialization to work correctly.  Additionally, the response that you say you are receiving does not return a List<PaymentResponse>, it is only returning one instance.  So attempting to deserialize to a list might fail.

Comment: Thank you @mreyeros I use  a property of type Data and problem soleved. But the response  return a List.